# How to check if class is based on other abstract class

Tags: oop, dart, extends

How can I check if my object of type `A` extends type `B` when the instance only extending `B` but is of type `C`.

For example:

```
abstract class A {
}

abstract class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

A myA = C();
```

I want to test if `myA` is extends `B` class (which it is in the example).

Tested the following

```
if (myA.runtimeType is B) // return false

if (myA.runtimeType == B) // return false

if (myA == B) // return false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `.runtimeType` and use the `is` operator like this

```
if (myA is B) // return true
```

Than the statement will return `true` like you want if `myA` is extends `B` even if it is not directly instance of `B`.